# Сравнить Object и Int

Tags: java

Как сравнить Object и Int.

```
Object может быть (примитивные типы)
 1.byte
 2.int
 3.long
 4.double
 (чем оно может быть заранее известно)
```

При сравнении выскакивают исключения(нельзя сравнить Int и Long). Как это можно реализовать без приведений к String.

Comment: Int нужно скастовать к Long - (Long)someInt

Comment: Тоже так подумал, щяс пробую реализовать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то как-то так ([ideone](https://ideone.com/ZFz5oy)):

```
public static int compare(Object lhs, Integer rhs) {
    if (lhs instanceof Double) {
        return Double.compare((Double) lhs, rhs);
    } else if (lhs instanceof Long) {
        return Long.compare((Long) lhs, rhs);
    } else if (lhs instanceof Integer) {
        return Integer.compare((Integer) lhs, rhs);
    } else if (lhs instanceof Byte) {
        return Integer.compare(((Byte) lhs).intValue(), rhs);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ок, спасибо оказывается второй аргумент как Object это не гуд. И кстате чего используете Обьект Integer а не примитивный тип int?(памяти куда больше обьект кушает) И  instanceof самый медленный оператор(но как вариант к вопросу ок). Спасибо.

Comment: Если использовать примитивный тип `int`, то он все равно будет приведен к тому или иному типу (Integer, Double и т.п.). По второму вопросу: раньше так и было, но jvm не стоит на месте и сейчас этот оператор не такой уж и медленный + другого способа определить реальный тип `lhs` в Java я не припомню.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/124909/